# best way to implement a method in JS classes?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor

What of this implementations is more useful ? The first one sets a calculation as prop, the second one sets the same calculation with a getter and the third one sets the calculation as a method.

The goal is to keep the code as simple as possible.

```
class SocialKPersona {
    constructor (palsInbiz, inFirstGradeNet, expYears){
      this.palsInbiz = palsInbiz;
      this.inFirstGradeNet = inFirstGradeNet;
      this.expYears = expYears;
      this.socialStrengthcalc = `SocialPersona index is ${(this.palsInbiz * this.inFirstGradeNet) / this.expYears}`
    }
}
const p1SocialPersona = new SocialKPersona (1, 500, 8);
console.log(p1SocialPersona.socialStrengthcalc);//SocialPersona index is 62.5
```

```
class SocialKPersona {
    constructor (palsInbiz, inFirstGradeNet, expYears){
        this.palsInbiz = palsInbiz;
        this.inFirstGradeNet = inFirstGradeNet;
        this.expYears = expYears;
    }
    get socialStrength (){
        return this.socialStrengthCalc;
    }    
    socialStrengthCalc(){
        return `SocialPersona index is ${(this.palsInbiz * this.inFirstGradeNet) / this.expYears}`
    }
}
const p1SocialPersona = new SocialKPersona (1, 500, 8);
console.log(p1SocialPersona.socialStrength());//SocialPersona index is 62.5
```

```
class SocialKPersona {
    constructor (palsInbiz, inFirstGradeNet, expYears){
      this.palsInbiz = palsInbiz;
      this.inFirstGradeNet = inFirstGradeNet;
      this.expYears = expYears;
    }    
    socialStrengthcalc(){
        return `SocialPersona index is ${(this.palsInbiz * this.inFirstGradeNet) / this.expYears}`
    }
}
const p1SocialPersona = new SocialKPersona (1, 500, 8);
console.log(p1SocialPersona.socialStrengthcalc());//SocialPersona index is 62.5
```

Comment: if the value never changes, go with the first. if it does change, go with the 3rd. stay away from redundant getters, they aren't used that often and thus are potentially more confusing to debug.

Comment: A getter that returns another method is quite weird. I would've understood if the getter did return the value.